# unwanted character in jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

i am using jquery ui tabs for my own custom image gallery, so i didn't load the css it comes with. in firefox there is nothing wrong, but in IE and chrome there is this dash character.

in the view source you don't see it, but Inspect Element in chrome shows me:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tab-9">_</a></li>
```

I tried doing something like `.ui-corner-top{display:none !important;}` but that kills off the tabs completely.

[image]

Comment: jQuery replaces whitespace in your tabs with an underscore. Is there a reason your tabs don't have text in them?

Comment: they do have text and the tab system is functioning fine. but somewhere behind the scenes it think they're empty though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution.

```
<a href=""><!--
   spaces here
-->Link text<!--
   spaces there
--></a>
```

You just have to comment out all spaces before and after the main link text.

Comment: i don't seem to have access to the anchor code that i listed above. jquery inserts it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some extra jQuery after you initiate the tabs to remove the character:

```
$('.ui-corner-top').find('a').html('&nbsp;');
```

Comment: this looks like the easiest solution, but it didn't work. going to plug away with it though.

Comment: it looks like that removes the contents of the tab navigation, and leaves the unwanted character in place.